# ¿Como se resuelve este ejercicio sin usar bucle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles

Queremos hacer una fila de ladrillos que tenga pulgadas de meta de largo. Tenemos un número de ladrillos pequeños (1 pulgada cada uno) y ladrillos grandes (5 pulgadas cada uno). Vuelva True si es posible hacer la meta eligiendo entre los ladrillos dados.

Función:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
.
.
.
```

Ejemplos:

`make_bricks(3, 1, 8)` → `True`

`make_bricks(3, 1, 9)` → `False`

`make_bricks(3, 2, 10)` → `True`

Comment: Pues seria bueno que pusieras que es lo que llevas y no solo el ejercicio que tienes que hacer. Otra cosa tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver (Desde mi punto de vista), con la respuesta que quieres obtener.

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de que creo que no has contado el enunciado completo del problema, una solución sin *usar bucles* sería usando **combinaciones**:

```
from itertools import combinations

def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    bricks = [1]*small+[5]*big
    return any(sum(lst)==goal 
               for n in range(len(bricks)+1)
               for lst in combinations(bricks,n) )
```

Es un algoritmo de fuerza bruta, muy poco eficiente. Pero es una solución para casos sencillos.

---

**Editado**

Vamos a resolverlo sin bucles ni recursividad:

Con suficientes ladrillos pequeños la solución sería trivial:

```
goal <= small
```

Calculemos entonces cuántos ladrillos grandes vamos a usar:

```
nbig = min(big, goal // 5)
```

Lo que nos quede para llegar a la meta tiene que hacerse con ladrillos pequeños:

```
(goal - nbig*5) <= small
```

Finalmente:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):

    nbig = min(big, goal // 5)

    return (goal - nbig*5) <= small
```

Un ejemplo usando sólo ladrillos pequeños para comprobar esta solución:

```
make_bricks(30, 0, 10) --> True
```

Comment: Pero ahí estas usando el bucle for

Comment: Con una definición amplia de bucle se podrían ver como tales. Pero hablando con propiedad se trataría de un *generador* que transforma una secuencia manteniendo el orden. Algunas diferencias: no existe estado de control, no se evalua mientras no se solicite (*laziness*), es posible su paralelización, ... Si no quieres usar bucles, al menos precisa cómo tendría que hacerse para que lo tengamos claro (¿ *recursividad*, tal vez?).

Comment: Es un ejercicio que lo saque de aquí https://codingbat.com/prob/p118406

Comment: Lo que dice este enunciado es que *"es posible hacerlo sin bucles"*. Mi sugerencia es que lo intentes con bucles para entender la dinámica, aunque no des con una solución completa, y luego intenta dar con la solución usando recursividad (que es como se solucionan estos problemas tipo).